# Enter data in geography column in SQL Server management studio

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqlgeography

I've created a new table in SQL Server Management Studio, which includes a Geography column.
Now, I'm trying to enter data in this column using the SSMS UI, but I just can't find the right way of doing it.

So, how can that be done?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I wouldn't think SSMS natively supports doing this with a nice interface (e.g. a map). Maybe there's some add-on to allow this, or likely some 3rd party app.

If you're happy with doing it in SQL, try this:

```
UPDATE tableName SET geographyColumn = geography::Point(47.65100, -122.34900, 4326)
```

Derived from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933811.aspx).

[Here](http://colinmackay.scot/2008/02/07/different-ways-to-add-point-data-in-sql-server-2008/) are 4 more ways to do the same.

Comment: I understand the first 2 parameter in the Point() method are the lat/long and the 3rd is the SRID. However; what does the value 4326 represent? I can not find any info anywhere which indicates what I should specify.

Comment: @AndyClark This query should answer your question.

select * from sys.spatial_reference_systems
where spatial_reference_id = 4326

Comment: Is 4326 belong to special know system, since I've seen it in many examples around the web?

Comment: It represents WGS 84 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System

Answer (score 7):

If editing a table cell *a la mano* just type in

```
POINT (2.434548 48.858319 4326)
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer!